# Building a mobile friendly browser game - Pure JS, Jquery, Flash, Unity, or WebGL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flash

I am interested in making mobile friendly browser games, and was wondering if I should stick too classical JS/CSS3 (and HTML5?), jQuery, flash, webGL technology, or the unity framework.

Which of these is the easiest to work with and also the most effective for rendering graphics in the browser at 60FPS?

Comment: In addition to @charlietfl without knowing what type of game you're aiming at this question is way too broad.

Comment: I flagged his comment as being non-constructive.  So I shouldn't have added flash because Apple doesn't like it, flash games dominated the web for a long period of time, and thought I would include it out of curiosity on why it was used so much for the early years of browser games.

Comment: I guess you didn't read it. Flash won't run on iPhone / iPad

Comment: @DavidStampher No you shouldn't have added it because its not *mobile friendly*...

Comment: "More than 20,000 apps in mobile markets, like the Apple App Store and Google Play, are built using Flash technology."

Source: http://www.adobe.com/products/flashruntimes/statistics.html

Comment: "*apps in mobile markets*" != *browser* ...

Comment: "mobile friendly" != browser

So remove "browser" from my original question, and flash is a valid choice apparently.  If 20.000 Android and iOS apps use it.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things are moving in the direction of the HTML5 canvas. It has good browser support and works great on mobile devices (where Flash is not even an option). You will find yourself very limited if you use HTML elements and move them around with JavaScript. With the canvas you are still writing JavaScript, but only modifying one HTML element: the canvas.

Comment: Hi ryan, have you heard of the Unity framework/IDE?  Your response was helpful, but wondering how it compares to HTML5?  Also is HTML 5 canvas rendering hardware accelerated, while JS is not?

Comment: Unity is probably the best option for building professional grade games. I'm not a game developer but I imagine you would pay for the power of Unity in time spent learning it, which may be more than you're bargaining for. The HTML5 canvas works natively in the browser and has a very low learning curve. There are frameworks for getting off the ground quicker, but you can have a working prototype very quickly with pure JS code. The canvas is a practical choice for that reason, but what really attracts me to it is the versatility. You can use it with bar graphs, google maps, etc.

Comment: Alright, thank you.  It really does help because I am just using JS right now for a game I'm making.  It works, but feels like I should be using HTML5 or Unity.  You confirmed that for me, but I am still curious about how much of an edge HTML5 has over JS in terms of rendering speed...

Comment: Sorry I ran out of characters! In hardware accelerated browsers your canvas will perform with native speed. But poor coding or technique will mask that. Be careful of any code that runs in a loop, on a timer, or by user keypress/drag. You will also see huge performance gains by using a second canvas (not in the DOM) as an image buffer. Then only redraw small sections that change and your game will be smooth.

Comment: Feel free to borrow from my chess project that uses the canvas for drawing and dragging pieces: https://github.com/ryancookdev/canvas-chess

Comment: Hey just saw your response.  I am guessing all modern browsers are hardware accelerated?  I will look into creating a image buffer using a 2nd canvas...and take a look at your chess game, I was actually going to code one myself just for learning purposes.